# Is this behavior of join normal?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

```
from datetime import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

columns = [ 'id1', 'id2', 'val' ]
ids = [ 'id1', 'id2' ]

vals1 = [
        (1, 'a', 1),
        (2, 'b', 4),
        (4, None, 1),
      ]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=vals1, schema=columns)

vals2 = [
        (1, 'a', 5),
        (3, 'c', 2),
        (4, None, 2),
      ]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=vals2, schema=columns)

df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed('val', 'val1')
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed('val', 'val2')

res_df = df1.join(df2, ids, 'full')

res_df.sort(ids).show()
```

And the result is

```
+---+----+----+----+
|id1| id2|val1|val2|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|   a|   1|   5|
|  2|   b|   4|null|
|  3|   c|null|   2|
|  4|null|   1|null|
|  4|null|null|   2|
+---+----+----+----+
```

i.e. there are 2 rows with the key [ 4, null ]
Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `NULL` does not equal `NULL` in comparisons as explained in the [`NULL` Semantics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-null-semantics.html) section of the documentation:

> Apache spark supports the standard comparison operators such as ‘>’, ‘>=’, ‘=’, ‘<’ and ‘<=’. The result of these operators is unknown or `NULL` when one of the operands or both the operands are unknown or `NULL`.

(AFAIK, this is standard SQL behaviour and not specific to Spark)

Furthermore:

> `WHERE`, `HAVING` operators filter rows based on the user specified condition. A `JOIN` operator is used to combine rows from two tables based on a join condition. For all the three operators, a condition expression is a boolean expression and can return `True`, `False` or `Unknown (NULL)`. They are “satisfied” if the result of the condition is `True`.

Comparing `NULL` to `NULL` produces `NULL`, which is not `True`, thus the `(4, NULL)` key in first table is not the same as the `(4, NULL)` key in the second table and so the join produces two distinct rows, one from joining the left row to a missing right row (`|  4|null|   1|null|`) and one from joining the right row to a missing left row (`|  4|null|null|   2|`).

Comment: That's strange, because "However, for the purpose of grouping and distinct processing, the two or more values with NULL data are grouped together into the same bucket. This behaviour is conformant with SQL standard and with other enterprise database management systems."

Comment: @user626528 true, `NULL` semantics are different when performing group aggregates or distinct. They won't be much useful otherwise.